# Find the values of $x$ so that $(x+b)^a \equiv x^a \pmod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For constants $a,b,p$ where $p$ is prime I want to find the values of $x$ such that $(x+b)^a \equiv x^a \pmod p$ and also $0 \leq x < p$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very vague question, there might not exist values of $x$ for particular values of $a,b$ say $a=1,b=1,p=5$.

No solution for this case!!

I don't think a general closed form expression of $x$ is easy to find.

Comment: Yes, I know that there can be no solutions for the given equation, but I need a way to proceed to find the value of `x` . For example by hit and trial method we get p=11,a=5,b=3

Comment: For particular given values of a,b and p, we can still try something but in general case i guess it's too difficult

Comment: Suggest a way as to how to proceed for the given equation.

Comment: I did one of these yesterday  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291288/finding-solutions-to-polynomial-modular-equations-like-x16-x6-equiv-0/2291292#2291292

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $p-1 = \varphi(p)$ are coprime then $x^a$ is injective over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ so no such $x$ exisits unless $b = 0$.

However is $\gcd(a,p-1) = d$ Then the map $x\mapsto x^a$ sends $(\mathbb{Z}_p^*,\cdot)$ to a subgroup isomprphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ where $n = \dfrac{p-1}{d}$ so there are exactly $d$ values of $x$ that are mapped to the same value.

However I don't think it's particularly easy to determine if any two of them have difference $b$.